# awk NR wrong with the total number of lines returned

Tags: awk

when awk NR was used for getting the total number of lines of a file, wrong number was returned. Could you help to find out what happened?

File 'test.txt' contents :

```
> 2012 09 10 30.0 8 14  
fdafadf  
> 2013 08 11 05.0 9 1.5  
fdafa  
> 2011 01 12 02.0 7 1.2  
daff
```

The average of the last column of records with '>' beginning was expected to get.

Code:

```
awk 'BEGIN{SUM=0}{/^> /{SUM=SUM+$6}END{print SUM/NR}' test.txt
```

With this code, the wrong mean of the last column was obtained instead of the right number 3. How can I get the right result with awk mission? Thanks

Comment: 8+9+7=24. 24/6=4. Why would you expect it to be 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following. This will take SUM of all line's last column and it will keep doing till Input_file is done with reading. It will alos count the number of occurrences of `>` lines because average means SUM divided by count(here count of lines), in `END` block of `awk` we could divide them and could get average as needed.

```
awk 'BEGIN{sum=0;count=0}/^>/{sum+=$NF;count++} END{print "avg="sum/count}' Input_file
```

If you want to take average of 6th column then use `$6` in spite of `$NF` in above code too.

***Explanation:*** Adding following only for explanation purposes.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk command/script here.
/^>/{                     ##Checking condition if a line starts from > then do following.
  sum+=$NF                ##Creating a variable named sum wohse value is adding in its own value of $NF last field of current line.
  count++                 ##Creating a variable named count whose value is incrementing by 1 each time cursor comes here.
}
END{                      ##END block of awk code here.
  print "avg="sum/count   ##Printing string avg= then dividing sum/count it will print the result of it.
}
' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Comment: Thanks, nice thought. But why not initialise the sum and count in the BEGIN block? Is it reasonable for that code? That is, is there any potential mistakes in the codes, which could happen in some cases?

Comment: @alex, yes you could mention them in `BEGIN` section too.

Comment: @alex, please do let us know if this helped you?

Comment: Yes, that helped me. But could you please edit your answer to a more rigorous one. Thanks

Comment: @alex, added full explanation for code too now, try to encourage people by up-voting if you find any answer on forums good and helpful, give it sometime and try to select an answer out of any as a correct one too.

Comment: Yep. Thanks for your comments. Great you are.